# How to use Campaign type in CampaignMember Object?

Tags: trigger

campaignMember.Campaign.type

this I am using but it is retreiving null values

Comment: are you using SOQL query to  fetch that field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you annotated this with tag `trigger`, I'm going to assume that you have a trigger on `CampaignMember`.

Since trigger context does not include any related Object fields (parents or children), you have to query (as @Ratan suggested) for the Campaign (parent) fields like this

```
set<ID> campaignIdSet = new set<ID> (); 
for (CampaignMember cm : Trigger.new) // collect parent campaign Ids
   campaignIdSet.add(cm.campaignId);

map<ID,Campaign> cIdToCampaignMap = new map<ID,Campaign> ( // fetch them into map
       [select id, type from Campaign where id IN : campaignIdSet]);

for (CampaignMember cm: Trigger.new) { // use them
  if (cIdToCampaignMap.get(cm.campaignId).type == ..) // do something
}
```